# ASP.NET Core Swagger Routing templates in Controller Route description

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I want to set up an multi tenant Application, the tenant is identified by an Route Template "Mandator".

So I'm using a RouteAttribute with a template at my controller:

```
 [Route("{Mandator}/api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]   
public class AssemblyController : ControllerBase
```

Now when I open the Swagger UI the field "Mandator" is generated in every request.
So this works, but how can I attach an (XML) decription to that field, that my Swagger-UI can show me some decription to that route template?
The default methods for Parameter dont't work here, because a class summary can't have a `<param>` tag inside.
Is there an attribute for describe route template parameters at class level?

Thanks

Comment: you could describe it in class summary itself? Also, each of  method in that controller will have `Mandator` parameter, you can use `<param>` tag over there, but, yes you have to repeat it for each method.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no  method to describe such path parameters. Then i have to use some of your workarounds